# Ionic 3 disable keyboard push

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a simple login form and every time that I hit the input, the keyboard pushes all my components, and what I want is that the keyboard stays on top as "absolute position".

Things that I have already tried:

## .css

```
ion-grid {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

## .ts

```
keyboard.disableScroll(true);
```

## app.module.ts

```
imports: [
  IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
    scrollAssist: false,
    autoFocusAssist: false)
  }
]
```

So I don't want the keyboard to push the content, just stay on top of the screen, even that stay over the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove keyboard plugin and add it again

Add this to `app.module.ts`

```
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, { scrollAssist: false, autoFocusAssist: false }),
```

and this to `app.component.ts`

```
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';

constructor(
  public platform: Platform,
  private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
  private statusBar: StatusBar,
  private keyboard: Keyboard
)


initializeApp() {
  this.keyboard.disableScroll(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. The problem is that I was testing the app in web view and of course, cordova component doesn't work on web view. So I generated the apk and test in a android phone. So that's it! Thanks @user9088454